# Rounding off spearmanr result to 3 decimal places

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

How do I round off spearmanr result to 3 decimal places if I want to put it as an annotation on my plot?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.stats
import numpy as np

percent = np.array([34.72,47.22,40.97,43.06,57.64,50.00,69.44])
year = np.array([2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(year,percent, marker='o')
ax.set_ylim(20,80)
ax.set_xticks(year)

ax.annotate(scipy.stats.spearmanr(year,percent), xy=(2009,70))

plt.show()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PylQG.png)
I want the annotation to remain inside the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformat the text in the annotation. Replace the second-to-last line with this:

```
r = scipy.stats.spearmanr(year, percent)
text = "correlation: {:.3f}, pvalue:{:.3f}".format(r.correlation, r.pvalue)
ax.annotate(text, xy=(2009,70))
```

Output

[image]